# "the page cannot be refreshed without resending the information" with http post method but not with get why?

Tags: servlets

When i forward a request from within a post method, a confirmation alert appear
 with a message "page cannot be refreshed without resending the information". 
 But this alert box doesn't appear when the forward is done from a get method.

What is the reason ?
 Please help.

Comment: Did either of those answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Because a POST, in the HTTP specifications, is intended for requests that are non-idempotent, because they modify state on the server (for example, by adding a new product to a category), that would be modified again if the request was resubmlited (it would create yet a new product in the category, for example).

A GET, on the other hand, is intended for requests that are idempotent. For example, a google search is idempotent. Searching twice for the same thing doesn't modify anything on the server, and resubmitting the same request doesn't have any unwanted effect.

The browser expects web applications to respect this convention, and thus warns the user about this unwanted side-effect before re-submitting a POST request.

The usual practice is to follow the [post-redirect-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern to let the user refresh after a post without this annoying popup, and without unwanted side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

Because a GET request includes those parameters in the URL (e.g. the URL ends with
 `?param1=foo&param2=bar`).  GET requests usually don't involve sensitive data or actions that change state of the server.  From the URL, you know what you're sending.

With a POST, the parameters are "hidden", submitted in the background as part of your HTTP request, and you can't see them by looking at the URL.  Those params cause the server to change state, and it could cause issues if that same data was transmitted twice (e.g. you'd accidentally purchase something twice from a web store).  The browser lets you know in case you don't realize you'd be resending it.